# Get values from same index using .random in a view SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, swiftui

I have an object that contains a name and description and I would like to display the corresponding data for these two but im stuck since I can only call either name or description to display using my func random().

I think I need to save the return index in a variable but just can't seem to work around it...

```
struct PinWidgetView: View {

let place: [Place]

func random() -> Place? {

    guard !self.place.isEmpty else { return nil }
    
    let allPlaces = self.place
    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<allPlaces.count)
    return allPlaces[randomIndex]
}

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Image("background")
            .resizable()
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
            .shadow(radius: 7)
            .scaledToFit()
        Text(random()?.name ?? "") <--------
            .font(.caption)
        Text(random()?.description ?? "") <-----------
            .font(.caption2)
    }
    .padding()
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this.  Here's a basic one:

```
struct PinWidgetView: View {

    let place: [Place]
    
    @State var currentPlace : Place?

    func random() -> Place? {

        guard !self.place.isEmpty else { return nil }
        
        let allPlaces = self.place
        let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<allPlaces.count)
        return allPlaces[randomIndex]
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
                .shadow(radius: 7)
                .scaledToFit()
            Text(currentPlace?.name ?? "")
                .font(.caption)
            Text(currentPlace?.description ?? "")
                .font(.caption2)
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            currentPlace = random()
        }
    }
}
```

In this scenario, when `PinWidgetView` appears (`onAppear`) it calls `random()` and stores the result in a `@State` variable (`currentPlace`).  Then, you can refer to `currentPlace` in your Text views.

You could also change your random function to just return an index and store that in the @State variable instead of the `Place` itself.

Another way that is probably a little lesson conventional is to abstract your Text views into a new subview and do something like this:

```
struct CurrentPlaceView : View {
    var place : Place
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(place.name)
            Text(place.description)
        }
    }
}

....
var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Image("background")
                    .resizable()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
                    .shadow(radius: 7)
                    .scaledToFit()
                if let place = random() {
                    CurrentPlaceView(place: place)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `randomElement()` method on `Array` which returns optional element. You also do not need the whole array of places in your struct as you are not using it. You can pass it into the initialiser and then just capture one random element to use in the `View`.

```
struct PinWidgetView: View {
    
    private let randomPlace: Place?
    
    public init(places: [Place]) {
        randomPlace = places.randomElement()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
                .shadow(radius: 7)
                .scaledToFit()
            Text(randomPlace?.name ?? "")
                .font(.caption)
            Text(randomPlace?.description ?? "")
                .font(.caption2)
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}
```